# Moment() vs predefined Moment().endof date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

i have a moment object called date :

> ( Tue Apr 09 2019 00:00:00 ...)

I want to replace it with the same day at the lase minute like this :

> (Tue Apr 09 2019 23:59:59 ...)

I tried to use `var date_end = moment().endOf(date)`,

but it only works if i put (day, week or year)
is it possible to use endOf or there is an other solution?

Comment: unable to understand your query

Comment: moment().endOf('day') will produce this output  =>Tue Apr 09 2019 23:59:59

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan yeah but i want it on a specific date not today

Comment: i have answer here below with specific date object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a moment object you can just do `date.endOf('day')`. I think you're misunderstanding the documentation.

```js
var date = moment('2019-04-09')
console.log('Before endOf', date.format())
date = date.endOf('day')
console.log('after endOf', date.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

> [End of time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/)
>
> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the end of a unit of
>   time.
>
> This is the same as moment#startOf, only instead of setting to the
>   start of a unit of time, it sets to the end of a unit of time.
>
> `moment().endOf("year"); // set the moment to 12-31 23:59:59.999 this year`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `endOf` after parsing your string date with `moment()`

Or you could just set the hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds manually

```js
let myMoment = moment('2019-04-09').endOf('day');
console.log(myMoment);

let myMoment2 = moment('2019-04-09').hour(23).minute(59).second(0).milliseconds(0);
console.log(myMoment2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need the endof on the variable date (moment object) not today

Comment: @mike You just have to parse your variable value with moment first, like this: `moment(yourVariable).endOf('day')`

Comment: @mike I've updated my answer to parse your date value '2019-04-09'

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the particular date in moment string and get end of day

```js
date = moment(new Date('Tue Apr 09 2019 00:00:00'));
console.log('End of day = ' + date.endOf('day').toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: i want to use endof on a specific date not the today's date

Comment: today is not 9 April today is 15th april my answer works on 9th